# The getter 'iterator' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: iterator

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo un FutureBuilder, la cual recibe la data de un archivo json.
Solo algunas veces sale este error, y he notado que a veces trae la respuesta vacía y otras no.
Buscando la solución decía que tenia que inicializar la data, funciono en un momento y pensé que ya estaba pero volvió a suceder.

[image: codigo]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: probablemente snapshot.data es nulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probablemente el problema sea que estás retornando directamente un ListView sin antes esperar que el snapshot tenga información (snapshot.hasData). Para esto puedes revisar el estado del snapshot y mandar algún otro Widget en lo que tu future (superioresProvider.cargarData('superiores.json')) se está ejecutando. Si simplemente no quieres mostrar nada puedes retornar un Container. Si quieres mostrar que se está cargando puedes mostrar un CircularProgressIndicator.

```
child: FutureBuilder(
    future: _miMetodoFuture(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        /*
        Código que se va a ejecutar una vez que el future haya sido ejecutado.
        */

        //Retornamos el Widget que se va a mostrar cuando el snapshot se haya ejecutado.
        return ListView();
      } else {
        /*
        Código que se va a ejecutar mientras el snapshot aún no está completo.
        */

        //Retornamos el Widget que se va a mostrar cuando el snapshot
        // esté esperando (ConnectionState.waiting) o tenga otro estado.
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
        // return Container() ;
      }
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Excelente idea! Muchas gracias, me funciono.